Keep xml formatting when parsing
I am using dart/Flutter package xml 6.5.0 to parse xml documents. Parsing content with
element.findElements("content").first.innerText

gives my the content,  but xml formatting is lost.
I would like to keep the xml formatting (at least   linebreaks ).  Is that possible?

I'm not sure I understand the problem. Can you show the code that does something with this innerText that doesn't do what you expect it to do? It'd also be good if you show your XML input, and how you initialize element. If you haven't before/recently, I recommend reading How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Please update the question showing a fragment of xml, what you expect to get and what you actually get.

The answer is to replace innerText with innerXml in the code snippet; ie.
 findElements("content").first.innerXml

